How to disable segfault handler in go
I need a target executable for some test code that  exits due to a SIGSEGV
Right now I have some code like this:
//go:generate bash -c "cc -x c  <(echo 'int main() { return *(int*)0; }') -o segv.bin"

func TestSignalledSegV(t *testing.T) {
    if _, err := os.Stat("./segv.bin"); errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
        t.Skipf("To enable this test, run go generate ./...")
    }
    cwd, err := os.Getwd()
    require.NoError(t, err)

    k := scriptJobTest(t, `
        echo start
        exec `+cwd+`/segv.bin
    `)
    k.requireOutput("start")
    k.requireTerminalState("signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)")
}

I'd like to eliminate the need for an external C compiler for the test.
I tried some code like this:
    var f func()
    f()

Or even this:
    p := unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(0x1000))
    f := *(*func())(p)
    f()

but instead of terminating due to SIGSEGV, it hits the fault handler and ultimately does an exit(2)
How do I disable the fault handler?

Calling a nil func terminates with a segfault, but prints a different message. Can you change the expected message to test what it prints?

I need to test the actual signal, not the output.... I think you may be mistaken, just because it says SIGSEGV in the output doesn't mean that the process terminated.  You may be looking at the go segfault handler that is printing that message, at the end does it say "exit status 2" ?   If you were to try to run it with exec.Command, the ProcesState should have Signaled() == true

Does it mean ProcessState.Signaled() is false in your case?

Yes, it is is ProcessState.Exited() == true... perhaps I should make a complete minimal example

You might find better answers for this on golang-nuts mailing list.
